# Crystal reports array not adding items to array after the first item in the group

Tags: crystal-reports-2016

I have two reports set up the same way one works yet the other does not.
I initialize the variables in the first group

```
 shared StringVar Array WcAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Array ShAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Shstr :="";
 shared StringVar Array RhAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Array UcAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Array TcAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Array BuAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Array RqAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Array SqAr := [""];
 shared StringVar Array BcAr := [""];
 shared NumberVar x := 1;
```

I then load the array in Group 4(Work Center)

```
 shared StringVar Array WcAr;
 shared StringVar Array ShAr;
 shared StringVar Shstr :="";
 shared StringVar Array RhAr;
 shared StringVar Array UcAr;
 shared StringVar Array TcAr;
 shared StringVar Array BuAr;
 shared StringVar Array RqAr;
 shared StringVar Array SqAr;
 shared StringVar Array BcAr;
 shared NumberVar x;

 (if not IsNull({@Work Center}) then WcAr [x] := {@Work Center};
   ReDim preserve WcAr[UBound (WcAr)+1];
   ShAr [x] := Cstr({Job_Operation.Act_Setup_Hrs},"####.##",2,",",".");
   ReDim preserve ShAr[UBound (ShAr)+1];
   RhAr [x] := Cstr({Job_Operation.Act_Run_Hrs},"####.##",2,",",".");
   ReDim preserve RhAr[UBound (RhAr)+1];
   UcAr [x] := Cstr({Job_Operation.Act_Unit_Cost},"####.##",2,",",".");
   ReDim preserve UcAr[UBound (UcAr)+1];
   TcAr [x] := Cstr({Job_Operation.Act_Total_Cost}+ 
      {Job_Operation.Act_Run_Labor},"####.##",2,",",".");
   ReDim preserve TcAr[UBound (TcAr)+1];
   x := x+1;);
```

I output these in the group footer using for each array

```
  shared StringVar Array WcAr;
  Join(WcAr,ChrW(10));
```

Only the first item is added to any of the arrays.  x has incremented and is equal to 17 which indicates it going through the formula.  I have tried without the if statement and anything else I can think of but I always get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

That should work, at least for your `WcAr`. As you're using Chr(10) as divider for the array elements, I guess you just see only the first element because the field formatting does not allow it to increase. => Either activate "Can grow" in output field format, or use another divider.

My test scenario is these three formulae, where COMMAND.STRING is the input field of course:

**init**

```
shared StringVar Array WcAr := [""];
shared NumberVar x := 1;
```

**add**

```
shared StringVar Array WcAr;
shared NumberVar x;

WcAr [x] := {COMMAND.STRING};
ReDim preserve WcAr[UBound (WcAr)+1];
x := x+1;
```

**output**

```
shared StringVar Array WcAr;
Join(WcAr,',');
```

**Important:** The add formula field must be placed in a repeated section, in my case it's the detail section, inyour case probably a group header. The output formula can only show the collected values when it's placed in a section after the one where the last value is collected (or in it).

Comment: It really is only adding the first element to the array.  I have tried everything to get more but it never does.  The Shstr variable is a string that concatenated each item that would be in the array.  It only showed the first item.  It was not a matter of field formatting.  I made sure the field would show everything it could possibly have.

Comment: Hi @TerryS, I updated my answer with details from a reproducible example. Maybe your formula field that collects the values is not positioned correctly in the report. I do also remember issues when these fields are suppressed, so try to leave them visible for troubleshooting.

Comment: I was sure that I had everything formatted correctly.  I checked again to make sure and the can grow box was not checked.  I selected it and it now works much better, although I'm a bit puzzled why the string did not concatenate after the first item, the divider for it was ":"  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer.